# Getting command Injection in Lodash

Tags: javascript, npm, lodash, fortify, commandinjection

Recently , I am facing below vulnerability on my security scan

Security scan results

```
Explanation: The `lodash` package is vulnerable to Command Injection. The `template` function in the `lodash.js` and `template.js` files does not properly ensure the `variable` property of the `options` parameter to be a valid EcmaScript. An attacker can exploit this vulnerability by passing a template with malicious JavaScript in it to the affected function. This will result in Remote Code Execution.
```

*Note:* This vulnerability is due to an insufficient fix for CVE-2021-23337.

Detection: The application is vulnerable by using this component.

Recommendation: There is no non-vulnerable upgrade path for this component/package. We recommend investigating alternative components or a potential mitigating control.

When I run npm audit, I see this is vulnerabilities.Though , All of  my packages are updated in Package.Json file still I am getting this error

NPM audit results:

```
{
 High    Command Injection in lodash                     
 Package loadash
 Patched in      >=4.17.21
 Dependency ofgrunt-maven-deploy [dev]
  Path            grunt-maven-deploy >     grunt > grunt-legacy-log >               
              grunt-legacy-log-utils > lodash                               
More info       https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-35jh-r3h4-6jhm  


    
High    Command Injection in lodash                                                                
Patched in      >=4.17.21                                                     
Dependency of   grunt-maven-deploy [dev] 
Path            grunt-maven-deploy > grunt > grunt-legacy-log > lodash     
More info       https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-35jh-r3h4-6jhm   
}

“Package.json”
{
“Grunt” : “1.4.1”
“Grunt-cli”: “1.4.3”
“Grunt-maven-deploy” :”0.2.1”
“Grunt-run”: “0.8.1”
“Grunt-tslint”: “5.0.2”
}
```

Could someone please explain and help me to resolve this issue

Thanks